# How to run a PowerShell "multiline-oneliner" from cmd.exe?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I'd like to copy/paste some PowerShells commands from cmd.exe
Say `Write-Output "first line"` and `Write-Output "second line"`

The very basic way is:

```
powershell  -NoProfile  -Command  "Write-Output 'first line'";  
powershell  -NoProfile  -Command  "Write-Output 'second line'";
```

Works perfectly but this launch PowerShell once for each command.
A good improvement is:

```
powershell  -NoProfile  -Command  "Write-Output 'first line'; Write-Output 'second line'"
```

But what about some pretty formatting?

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "
    Write-Output 'first line';
    Write-Output 'second line';
"
```

I tried with sevral combinations of ` (PowerShell line continuation) and ^ (cmd.exe line continuation) without success.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Easiest solution, put everything inside a .ps1 file, and use `powershell -noprofile -file "script.ps1"`. Although I would recommend a full powerscript over a batch script every day, if you are doing this from batch, then consider echo lines >> file.ps1, execute it, then remove file.ps1 from your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by pasting this text into CMD :

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    Write-Output 'first line'; ^
    Write-Output 'second line';
                                   <== this is an empty line
```

The empty last line at the end of the text is required
when pasting in order to avoid the need to press
<kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute.
This does not apply when typing this long command by hand.

It looks like this on execution :

[image]

Comment: So simple, many thanks. In each test I did, I used the quotes. I personnaly not use the final empty line because I prefer to check if the copy/paste seems correct (I often do the copy/paste through RPD/TeamViewer/etc).